# This is a homework assignment in a beginning Java class

Tags: java

I am attempting to write a program that takes an input from the user and uses that to decide the 'difficulty' of the game by setting variables for health.  After this is decided, I need to use those new values in another loop for the fight sequence.  The second sequence requires the user to choose an attack with values specific to that.  I can't figure out how to make the variables change once the user chooses the appropriate attack.  Since this is homework, I do not want the answer, but a suggestion of what methods I should look at to be able to do this would be great. The last bit is what gives me an error saying 'x might not have been initialized'.  Thank you for your time, even if you decide not to help. This is what I have so far:
*Edited to close brackets*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomName {

    public static void main(String []args) {    
        int x; //antagonist health
        int y;//protagonist health

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //Health of the characters involved.
        int a = input.nextInt();

        if(a == 1) {
            x = 40;
            y = 75;
        }

        if(a == 2) {
            x = 50;
            y = 50;
        }

        if(a == 3) {
            x = 75;
            y = 40;
        }          
        //Ends difficulty block

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int b  = console.nextInt(); 

        if(a == 1) {
            x = x -10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you format your code, because you have lots of `{` without matching `}` I would only wrap `System.in` once and call `input.readLine()` after `nextInt()` to discard the rest of the line.

Comment: Well, nothing is stopping the user from entering anything else than 1, 2 or 3 for `a`. In that case, `x` will not have been initialized. My advice would be to remove 1 of the if statements, and use those values of `x` and `y` as defaults. e.g. remove the first `if`, and declare them as `int x = 40; int y = 75;`.

Comment: You should probably use `switch` or `if - else if` instead of multiple `if` statements and and handle the default value for `x` in a `else` block or in `default:` if you are using the switch when the input is incorrect

Comment: As much as I hate recommending a switch, this would be an ideal case for it. You have a very simple input that you want to match against (notice all your `if`s are just checking equality against numbers), and need a default case when the user enters bad input (literally `case default:`).

Answer (score 0):

Many closing brackets are missing. Go through the code by hand and keep a track of each pair of brackets. You will figure out where to close them.

Comment: Sorry, the brackets are closed, I left out the print statements at the end of each of the if statements including the bracket closings.

Comment: Please do not do such omissions while describing the problem. Include the complete code.

Comment: My apologies.  It didn't occur to me that they were missing.